# How can I get value in JQuery from variable stored with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a chart where I want to get values from variables stored in Model.
My Jquery Code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
   var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'bar',
     data: {
       labels: ['Quality', 'Service', 'Cleanliness', 'Staff'],
       datasets: [{
         label: 'Average Ratings',
         data: [0,1,2,4,5],
         backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,62,0.6)"
       }]},

   });
```

My Model:

```
 public function chart_data()
    {
        $total = $this->db->query("SELECT 
                     ROUND(count((service_ans_1)+(service_ans_2)+(service_ans_3)+(quality_ans_1)+(quality_ans_2)+(quality_ans_3)+(quality_ans_4)+(cleanliness_ans_1)+(cleanliness_ans_2)+(cleanliness_ans_3)+(cleanliness_ans_4)+(cleanliness_ans_5)+(staff_ans_1)+(staff_ans_2)+(staff_ans_3))) as total from `dine_in_feedback` as f")->row()->total;

        $service    = $this->db->query("SELECT 
                        ROUND(avg(((service_ans_1)+(service_ans_2)+(service_ans_3))/3)) as service from `dine_in_feedback` as f")->row()->service;
        $quality    = $this->db->query("SELECT 
                    ROUND(avg(((quality_ans_1)+(quality_ans_2)+(quality_ans_3)+(quality_ans_4))/4)) as quality from `dine_in_feedback` as f")->row()->quality;
        $clean    = $this->db->query("SELECT 
                    ROUND(avg(((cleanliness_ans_1)+(cleanliness_ans_2)+(cleanliness_ans_3)+(cleanliness_ans_4)+(cleanliness_ans_5))/5)) as clean from `dine_in_feedback` as f")->row()->clean;
        $staff   = $this->db->query("SELECT 
                    ROUND(avg(((staff_ans_1)+(staff_ans_2)+(staff_ans_3))/15)) as staff from `dine_in_feedback` as f")->row()->staff;


        $result['service'] = $service / $total * 100;
        $result['quality'] = $quality / $total * 100;
        $result['clean'] = $clean / $total * 100;
        $result['staff'] = $staff / $total * 100;
        return $result;

    }
```

I want service,quality,clean and staff values in "data: [0,1,2,4,5]" like data:[value of service,value of quality,value of clean,value of staff]

Comment: You should have explained how you can access `function chart_data()` in your jquery, If your jquery is in view file, you should be able to access it with `$data = $model->chart_data();`, then use it in data like `data: [ <?= $data['service'] ?>,  <?= $data['quality'] ?> ...` etc.

Comment: Yes it is in view. Got it bro. Working great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You need to call model function "chart_data" from your controller for example:

```
$chart_data= $this->model_name->chart_data();
```

Then send $chart_data variable to your view like this:

```
$this->load->view('your view name', $chart_data);
```

After that you can use chart_data variable in your view like this:

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
   var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'bar',
     data: {
       labels: ['Quality', 'Service', 'Cleanliness', 'Staff'],
       datasets: [{
         label: 'Average Ratings',
         data: ['<?php echo $chart_data['service'] ?>','<?php echo $chart_data['quality'] ?>','<?php echo $chart_data['clean'] ?>','<?php echo $chart_data['staff'] ?>'],
         backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,62,0.6)"
       }]},

   });
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. Working great :) . I must say the way you explained everything. Thanks alot once again.

Comment: One more thing if you can help. The labels are now dynamically showing the data but I want x and y labels to be set as fixed.